# Calculating the given power of a complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$(-2\sqrt{3}+2i)^{-9}$

I tried solving it like I solved other problems, I calculated $r$ which is $4$ then got $4(\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}+\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}})$, then using an equation,

I got $4^{-9}(\sin90+\cos90)=4^{-9}(1+0)=4^{-9}$

But the answer is  $\frac{i}{2^{18}}$.

I understand that $\frac{1}{4^{9}}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2^{18}}$ but I don't understand how we got an $i$ in the answer.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Pleas see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

I presume the question is to find
$$(2\sqrt3+2i)^{-9}.$$
This equals
$$\left(4\left(\cos\frac\pi6+i\sin\frac\pi6\right)\right)^{-9}
=2^{-18}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{3\pi}2\right)
+i\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi}2\right)\right)=2^{-18}i$$
via de Moivre's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but may I ask how you got the i in your answer? I solved some other problems too but they didn't have i in the answer.

Comment: de Moivre's theorem : $(\cos t+i\sin t)^n=\cos nt+i\sin nt$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense I checked other problems and their sin was always zero. Thank you!